# How to get the numbers of characters in a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, localization, utf-8, character-encoding

It is UTF-8.
For example, 情報 is 2 characters while ラリー ペイジ is 6 characters.

Comment: When I use mb_strlen(), it is 6 for 情報 and 19 for ラリー ペイジ

Comment: FYI there is a space in "ラリー ペイジ" making it 7 chars

Comment: Try to specify the encoding you are using as the second parameter to mb_strlen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code

```
$a = "情報";
$b = "ラリーペイジ";

echo mb_strlen($a, 'UTF-8') . "\n";
echo mb_strlen($b, 'UTF-8') . "\n";
```

Result

```
2
6
```

Comment: Oh BTW i removed the space in ラリー ペイジ

Comment: This will probably get undefined results on characters which have no equivalent in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Code is changed to be more "safe"

Answer (score 0):

Use [mb_strlen](http://php.net/mb_strlen) för multibyte character encodings like UTF-8.

Comment: When I use mb_strlen(), it is 6 for 情報 and 19 for ラリー ペイジ

Comment: For some reason i get undefined function for mb_strlen :S

Comment: Question Mark, check that you have the mbstring extension installed and activated in PHP.

Comment: Steven, try to specify which encoding the string is in as the second parameter to mb_strlen. Maybe it failed to detect your encoding automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strlen(utf8_decode('情報'));`

Answer (score 0):

Even if the second argument of mb_strlen is said optional, it is actually needed, even if your internal encoding and your string's one are the same, for portability purposes.

```
mb_strlen('情報', 'UTF-8');
```

The same applies for most multi-byte functions, including mb_substr, for wich the utf8_decode option would not work at all.